# Always use services in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I've read by many people to not use AsyncTask for web requests, but rather use IntentService, since AsyncTask is bound the lifecycle of its activity. is that always the case? cause I'm making a social media app, And I wonder if each action the user makes should launch a service (for example, press like, add comment, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use AsyncTask, as you may have read, it is problematic on Activity recreate. However, you may use AsyncTaskLoader with LoaderManager, which is designed to fix the problem.

And there is one point you are wrong with IntentService, you do not **launch a service** everytime using IntentService. You are submitting requests to the same service only (unless it is being killed), and the IntentService pull requests from the stack.

Comment: aha .. Thx Derek .. could you refer me to a good tutorial that explains the best practice for using services in a good way for beginners

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService you should try to play with the sample code first. Just a side note, it is not an easy task to handle the activity recreation on Android, you may need some time to understand the whole structure.

Comment: I am sorry, this would be better: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a mixture of both. I use an IntentService when requesting/posting data from a server, then deserialising it and storing it locally. All this could take several seconds depending on the amount of data returned and the server's response time.

I would use an AsyncTask within an activity if I know that the request is going to be very quick. I use it for more fire and forget small tasks.

The important thing to bear in mind is that your AsyncTask is tied to your activity. And if your activity gets destroyed (due to an orientation change etc.) then you could easily have an NPE in the onPostExecute().

Comment: thx .. i would like to ask you for a specific case .. im my social media app, If someone adds a comment or press like, should I send it in a post request in a service or asynctask? and when returned, update the local sqlite DB and reload the list view?

Comment: I would probably handle something that complicated in an IntentService. I would use a BroadcastReceiver in my activity which the IntentService would notify when finished. Then the Activity could reload its UI.

Answer (score 0):

If the task you wish to perform is specific to a Context and is considered garbage once you leave the Context, such as if you consider the user session to be invalid once they leave, then an AsyncTask is a good choice.

However, if the task is specific to a context and may take a long time to perform and you want the user to be able to leave and come back later to see the result, a service may be well suited even though the task is specific to a Context.

If the task you wish to perform is applicable outside the scope of a Context, then a service may be better suitable.

If you just always use a service, you'll probably be over complicating your code.